# Webpage: Multiple scroll areas with variable height

Tags: html, css, web

I want to create a html page with a header of fixed height, a middle part with variable height and a footer with fixed height. The footer and the header shall not move when scrolling.

No problem so far.

But i want the midlle part to be divided, so that the right column and the left column have seperate scrollbars and scroll independently. This is possible with overflow:scroll as long as the parts have fixed heights. But i want them zu grow and shrink with the window.

I do not linke frames and i want to alter the contents of the 2 columns frequently using javascript (ajax).

What is the best way to create such a page?

Comment: What have you done so far, putting the header/footer sections in place?

Comment: I use a simple table layout with one div per column with style="overflow-y:scroll;height:500px;"  
But that doesn't change height when resizing the window

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've tested this in IE7/8 (not 6!) and recent versions of: Firefox, Chrome, Opera.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/ijoji3) (complete with boring colours)

The **HTML** is very simple:

```
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

On the other hand, the **CSS** is a bit more complicated:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding:0; border: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
#header, #middle, #footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
}
#header {
    background: #777;
    height: 150px;
    top: 0
}
#middle {
    background: #f00;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 150px
}
#footer {
    background: #777;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 0
}
#left, #right {
    overflow-y: scroll
}
#left {
    background: #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%
}
#right {
    background: #999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%
}
```

I will explain how the CSS works if you ask me to.

Comment: +1 @thirty Nice work. I didn't know you could set both the top _and_ bottom position of an element.

Comment: Note: You forgot to mention your most important line: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
Without it IE wont interpret it correctly...

Comment: @Floste: Correct, though adding a doctype is something that should *always* be done - it goes without saying.

Comment: The Live Demo doesn't reflect the answer...here is a CodePen that will https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/BajEeBw

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages on divs (and leave out the table).  For example, you might set a header at `height: 20%`, and two middle scrolling divs at `height: 70%; width: 50%; float:left;`.  This leaves the footer div at `height: 10%`. Changing the contents of the middle divs via ajax shouldn't change their height. But of course, this provides a variable, not fixed, header and footer.

*note: these numbers are just for illustrative purposes. You'll need to adjust them, including padding/margins, which are not accounted for.*

Comment: I do not want the footer or header to scale. Just the middle!!